# Oracle Cloud > utl_http fails with a ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure ORA-06512

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am working with a temporary Oracle Cloud account. What I thought was identical functionality works on the Apex Web Service, but not with UTL_HTTP. So this snippet works and returns the issue we are looking for.

```
DECLARE   
   L_json_response     varchar2(32767);
BEGIN   
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';   
   apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).Value := 'application/json';         
   L_json_response := apex_web_service.make_rest_request ( p_url => 
   'https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/BLABLA-23862', p_http_method => 'GET', 
    p_username => 'My.Username@mycompany', p_password => 'osBJWHhPasdffNVOQ5AA11D5'); -- Password is my Jira API Token      
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - 
  '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END;
```

I can't use the Apex web service in the end product, and we need to use UTL_HTTP. This snippet should from my understanding do the same:

```
DECLARE
    req utl_http.req;
    res utl_http.resp;
    url varchar2(4000) := 'https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/BLABLA-23862';
    buffer varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
    req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'GET');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
    utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' || utl_encode.base64_encode('my.msername@mycompany:osBJWHhPasdffNVOQ5AA11D5'));

    res := utl_http.get_response(req);
    utl_http.read_text(res, buffer);
END;
```

But returns:

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
> ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 639
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1415 ORA-06512...

Comment: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('');`. You need to set the wallet(with empty string parameter) before initial http request.
The following code snippet tested with in Oracle Cloud ATP (Autonomous Transition Processing) database:

1. Setup network ACL

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl  => 'my_acl.xml',
                                    description => 'ACL for http request.',
                                    principal => 'MY_USER',
                                    is_grant  => true,
                                    privilege => 'connect');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl => 'my_acl.xml',
                                       principal => 'MY_USER',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve');
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl => 'my_acl.xml', host => 'www.oracle.com');
END;
```

2. Test https request

```
DECLARE
  l_text VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('');
  l_text := UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('https://www.oracle.com/index.html');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_text);
END;
```

See [official document and example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC) (on the bottom of page):

Comment: The more I work on this, the more true this answer is. Official answer to this question although I had to work on it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In a way @OldProgrammer answered this the comment from 29-12-2020m but I don't know how to attribute the answer.

I needed to either couple the UTL_HTTP code to default wallet or create a new one. APEX_WEB_SERVICE probably does this implicitly while UTL_HTTP has to have it spelled out.

My question was for Oracle Cloud and I couldn't make the toolchain from OldProgrammers link work in Oracle Cloud. Rolled out a VM and it works.

Comment: I believe that the answer from @OldProgrammer is general solution for on-prem Oracle. For Oracle Cloud, please read the UTL_HTTP restriction here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC, in summary, you can only access external webservice via https on standard port 443, with public SSL certificate (self-signed certificate not allowed). For the time writing this comment, there is no way to create or update the wallet. Oracle audit and manage all trusted SSL certificate.